# How to Call a class within same package and same directory in java?

Tags: java

Basically I have:

```
package duck.reg.pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Test() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        DBConnect DB = new DBConnect();
    }
}
```

Class to call At Test.java:

```
package duck.reg.pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DBConnect {
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;

    public DBConnect(){
        System.out.println("Hi there!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Both File Directory Location:

```
C:\classes\duck\reg\pack\Test.java  +  DBConnect.java
```

The problem is that when I compile the program with command:

```
C:\classes\duck\reg\pack>javac -cp "C:\Users\Unknown\JavaEEWorkspace\lib\*" Test.java
```

This error is thrown:

> Test.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
>                   DBConnect connect = new DBConnect();

I googled a little and I found I could remove the `.java` Extension from Test while compiling it and I did so But Then I got this error:

> error: Class names, 'Test', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
>   1 error

All replies are much appreciated :)

Comment: You need to tell the compiler all the files related. Its not finding the DBConnect.java file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the compiler from the top package (which is at the root of the tree on the filesystem). So cd to

```
cd C:\classes
```

And run

```
javac -cp "C:\Users\Unknown\JavaEEWorkspace\lib\*" duck\reg\pack\*.java
```

Comment: You do not need to run the program from the top directory. That is why we have the classpath option. Why didn't you show the correct technique using the classpath and sourcepath?

Comment: And the "top" package (did you mean _default_ package?) Is not `/`. `/` is a directory, not a package.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use the -cp (or -classpath) option to specify the base directory of the package com.yyy, in order to locate DBConnect.

```
javac -cp "d:\lib\*" d:\myJavaProject\pkg\*.java
```

Comment: That won't help as long as DBConnect.java is not compiled. Even worse, if DBConnect.java has been changed since last compilation, this may result in effects not expected by the developer.

Answer (score -2):

write at the top

```
import duck.reg.pack.DBConnect;
```

in the class that you want to import it.

Why don't you use IntelliJ it will do it for you ?

Comment: classes in the same package does not need to be import. He is not specifying the BDConnect.java file to the compiler.